# Yui Mouse Coordinates over Element

Tags: yui, mouse-coordinates

I'm trying to determine if the mouse is over an element preferably with YUI if there is a method for that already.

Basically something like

function bool IsMouseOver(Element);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up checking it myself.

I have the region from the target element

```
var region = YAHOO.util.Dom.getRegion(this.element);
var top = region.top;
var left = region.left;
var bottom = region.bottom;
var right = region.right;
```

Then the mouse coordinates

```
var mouseXY = YAHOO.util.Event.getXY(e);
var mX = mouseXY[0];
var mY = mouseXY[1];
```

And then a simple if statement to check if the mouse coordinates were in the region

```
(mX > left && mX < right && mY > top && mY < bottom)
```